# What's the function like onLoadResource of Android WebView on iOS WkWebKit?

Tags: android, ios, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

I want to use a function like onLoadResource() of Android WebView in iOS WkWebKit.
If a function like onLoadResource() exists, Please put post in here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this.

```
func webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!)
```

It is part of the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol.